# Reasons why PHP stream_socket_enable_crypto() returns FALSE?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am setting up a ZF3 SMTP Mail transport to send messages to my own email server which I have set up using PostFix and Dovecot.

I keep getting the `'Unable to connect via TLS'` error which occurs when the `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` tries to enable TLS.

I tried with another email server (my ISP's email server) using TLS and it worked so it is not my code itself.

Since I have been able to connect Outlook to my email server, I know that the connection to smtp:587 to my server works and that authentication also works.

It's not an authentication issue since I do get path enabling TLS on the socket.

Does anyone have any suggestions of where the problem lies?  Or a list of things to check to isolate the issue?

EDIT:

If this additional info can help, I am using a self-signed CA certificate on my development machine.  To be precise, I am running PHP from Apache which uses a certificate that was generated from a self-signed CA.

Looking at the logs from postfix/submission, I seem to be getting an 'unkown CA' error.  Tried to add my self-signed CA to the list of CA on my server but this does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: From the documentation: "Returns TRUE on success, FALSE if negotiation has failed or 0 if there isn't enough data and you should try again (only for non-blocking sockets)." So if it's actually returning false, likely there's a mismatch between the methods supported by your server and those supported by PHP.

Comment: stream_socket_enable_crypto() returns false.  So far, I think the certificate used by the socket when enabling encryption is rejected by the remote.  Like I mentioned, I am using a certificate generated by a self-signed CA on my dev machine where the PHP script is running.  Using a virtual host on Apache to run the PHP script and the vhost uses that development certificate. How do I figure out which certificate my script is using?  The one associated with the vhost? Or is it another default certificate?

Comment: The certificate used by your web server has nothing to do with how PHP connects to other servers. If your mail server is using a self-signed certificate, you'll want to use `stream_socket_context_create()` to set the options to ensure that PHP recognizes that certificate.

Comment: The mail server is using a valid certificate issued by GoDaddy.  My server where the PHP code is running, uses a certificate issue by a self-signed CA (that I created for dev purposes).  Not very proficient in SSL/TLS so I am not sure yet which sides refuses to start encryption and logs on the mail server (Postfix/Dovecot) are pretty cryptic.

Comment: The certificate used by your web server is for talking to web browsers, not making network connections. If your mail server cert is trusted already, I'd go back to my original statement about mismatched encryption algorithms.

Comment: I got it to work.  The issue seemed to be with the server's certificate which is trusted by GoDaddy but somehow, the PHP client could not resolve the GoDaddy trust chain to its root.  I assume that, on Windows, PHP would use the Windows' certificate store to resolve it.  The server was not sending the entire CA chain, just the server`s certificate and signing CA (GoDaddy Secure CA G2).  I added the remaining chain to GoDaddy Class 2 CA and it worked.  Question is why the PHP client was not able to validate the CA all the way to the top.  Does PHP use a different CA store than windows?

Comment: No idea how Windows PHP would work, sorry.

Comment: According to PHP documentation, PHP will use the OS-managed cert store if the 'openssl.capath' is not set in php.ini.  My setup had 'openssl.capath' pointing to a CRT bundle.  By commenting it out, it worked and I assume that PHP went to Window's cert store to validate the CA.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 3):

After several investigations, it turns out that PHP on my local machine was not setup properly to validate trusted CAs.  I am running Bitnami's stack and PHP was setup to use a local CA bundle in the PHP installation directory.  This is set by the `openssl.capath=` directive in `php.ini`.

```
     openssl.capath=c:/bitnami/wampstack-5.6.34-0/php/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

The php.ini file has the following comment concerning `openssl.capath`:

```
     ; If openssl.cafile is not specified or if the CA file is not found, the
     ; directory pointed to by openssl.capath is searched for a suitable
     ; certificate. This value must be a correctly hashed certificate directory.
     ; Most users should not specify a value for this directive as PHP will
     ; attempt to use the OS-managed cert stores in its absence. If specified,
     ; this value may still be overridden on a per-stream basis via the "capath"
     ; SSL stream context option.
```

By commenting out the `openssl.capath` directive, PHP was able to use Window's cert store and find the CA associated with the cert used by the mail server.